# Join two mysql tables in different way in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have following mysql tables.

```
1. members
----------
|id |name|
----------
|001|aaa |
|002|bbb |
|003|ccc |
|004|ddd |
----------

2. membershipfees
----------------
|id |date      |
----------------
|001|2012-01-01|
|002|2012-01-01|
----------------
```

I want to show list of the members who not paid the fees for the current month. My php code is,

```
SELECT Members.id, Members.Name FROM Members
    LEFT JOIN MembershipFees
    ON Members.id = MembersipFees.id
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(MembershipFees.Date, '%Y%m') <> DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')
    ORDER BY Members.id ASC
```

But it shows 0 rows. Any suggestions please.

Comment: 'date ' is not a mysql date field, use one of the date types, your clearly using one of the text types

Comment: @Dagon I'm not sure about that: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: @alfasin mysql uses YYYY-MM-DD as the above is not, it cant be a date field

Comment: I think there is no problem with the date format. I've changed it to "YYYY-MM-DD". Still no result.

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka I think that you didn't understand what Dagon said: please check the type of the column membershipfees.date - is it really a DATE or is it VARCHAR ? If it's not of type DATE you cannot compare it as a DATE, you should use `STR_TO_DATE`

Comment: Yes Date is DATE type in mysql (not VARCHAR).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `MembersipFees.id IS NULL` condition is where clause. Also if `date` field is varchar column then you should be using `STR_TO_DATE` function.

```
SELECT Members.id, Members.Name
FROM Members
     LEFT JOIN membershipfees
        ON Members.id = membershipfees.id
           AND DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(membershipfees.`Date`, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y%m') = 
                           DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')
WHERE membershipfees.id IS NULL
ORDER BY Members.id ASC;
```

[**SEE SQLFIDDLE DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61c79/1)

Comment: You'are welcome! @alfasin: right in your case you don't need `STR_TO_DATE`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it right now, but please try and let me know if it works for you:

```
SELECT m.id, m.Name FROM Members m
Where not exists 
    (select 1 from membershipfees mm 
     where 
     mm.Date > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m')
     and mm.id = m.id)
```

**UPDATE:** 

It works [*for me*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b324f/2)

Comment: Sorry still no result. I am not aware how to use two SELECT statements in a query. I prefer JOIN..

Comment: Thanks alfasin. One more quiz. Isn't it better to use JOIN using than sub queries?

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka there is no `rule`. Try to run both queries with `EXPLAIN [your query]` and see which one runs better.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

You Just have to add **membershipfees.id IS NULL** condition to your query

```
SELECT members.id, members.Name  
FROM   members 
LEFT outer JOIN membershipfees 
ON       members.id = membershipfees.id 
and    DATE_FORMAT(membershipfees.Date, '%Y%m')
                          <> DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m') 
where  membershipfees.id IS NULL
ORDER BY members.id ASC
```

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka: I have updated my answer could u plz try now

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka: I have updated my answer.. I didnt notice that you have changed your date format in your question.. Please try now

Comment: Now it shows all the members who paid and not paid for the current month.!

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka: I have tested it, it shows only 3 ccc and
4 ddd.. could you please check again.. take the answer again.. you might be testing with old query

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort Joe. I copy and pasted your query. But still same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query..

```
SELECT Members.id, Members.Name FROM Members where id not in (select id from membershipfees WHERE DATE_FORMAT(MembershipFees.Date, '%Y%m') <> DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m') ORDER BY Members.id ASC)
```

Comment: click the link and you'll see ;)

Comment: No it's not, it should show every ID but `002` and it shows everything except `001`, here [*look*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b324f/13)